# why the sigmoid function will be 1 and 0 if we use a fully connected layer that produce a big enough positive(res negative )output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, statistics, computer-vision

HI I am using a fully connected network that uses sigmoid if we feed a a big enough weights the sigmoid function will finally become 1 or 0 , is there any solution to avoid this ?

and will this lead to classical sigmoid problems vanishing gradient or exploding gradient ?

Thank you

Comment: You can try using the ReLU activation function.

Comment: ShubhamPanchal  I need to calculate probability that is why I assume I am tied to sigmoid

Comment: if the function value becoming 0 or 1 due to float precision issues you could just add/subtract a small epsilon (like 1e-6), this should not hurt your results

Answer (score 0):

The sigmoid function is an activation function and would produce values between 0 and 1. So basically if you want values other than 0 and 1 you should not be using sigmoid. Secondly, if you are using sigmoid in the last layer of your network you can replace it by softmax function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the probability of different classes as the output, you should use **SOFTMAX** activation function.

[image: working of a softmax]

It outputs probability of all the classes based on the above formula.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of sigmoid is shown below

[image]

When you have very large weights because of the activation `sigmod(w^tx + b)` where `w and b`  your large weights you will end up with passing a very large positive or negative number to sigmoid functions. Very large positive number will return 1 and similarly very large negative number will return 0 by the sigmoid function (as shown in sigmoid graphs)).